# What are the credentials to use Azure blob in Jclouds?

Tags: azure-storage, jclouds

I m playing around with Jclouds. I managed to connect to my Amazon S3 account, and I m trying to do the same for Azure blob store. However I dont know what credentials should I fill in :

```
BlobStoreContext context = new BlobStoreContextFactory().createContext("azureblob", accesskeyid, secretkey);
```

So what it the accesskeyid and the secretkey?

I found some instrcutions here but they were not very helpful.
http://www.jclouds.org/documentation/quickstart/azure-storage/

In Azure blob, what you get is two access keys: a primary and secondary one. I tried to use these ones as accesskeyid and secretkey respectively but didnt work.

Anybody has an idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just found out that the credentials are as follows:

accessKeyId: storage account name

secretKey: Primary Access Key